# Different BCH code between encoder and decoder

Tags: coding-theory

I am searching for the mathematical properties of the BCH codes that could explain that if I encode a message with a BCH defined by $(m=6,n=63,k=24,t=7)$, I can decode that message correctly with another BCH defined by $(m=6,n=63,k=30,t=6)$.

I have some linear algebra knowledge, but not enough to quickly catch up on  the [BCH Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BCH_code). Is the above property normal or not (I'm programming so it could be a bug), and if yes why?

Thanks

Comment: The 7-error-correcting code is a subspace of the 6-error-correcting code. So if at most six errors occured the decoding algorithm of the bigger code will decode correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to tell without further information about the actual generating and parity check polynomials. However, Magma tells me that $X^{63}+1$ factorizes as below:

$$(X + 1)(X^2 + X + 1)(X^3 + X + 1)(X^3 + X^2 + 1)(X^6 + X + 1)(X^6 + X^3 + 1)$$
$$\times(X^6 + X^4 + X^2 + X + 1)(X^6 + X^4 + X^3 + X + 1)(X^6 + X^5 + 1)$$
$$\times (X^6 + X^5 +X^2 + X + 1)(X^6 + X^5 + X^3 + X^2 + 1)$$
$$\times (X^6 + X^5 + X^4 + X + 1)(X^6 + X^5 + X^4 + X^2 + 1)$$

Thus, provided you pick the generator polynomial of the dimension 30 BCH as a multiple of (by multiplying by another degree 6 irreducible) the one of dimension 24 (which is a product of 4 degree 6 irreducibles), and provided the two codes have consecutive null spectrum frequencies of length 2t=12 (for t=6) and 14 (for t=7) starting at m=7, things should work out, by guaranteeing codewords in the smaller code are also codewords of the larger code. By the way, the Wikipedia page [Cyclic Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_code) seems quite helpful, but of course don't rely on it 100%. Books by Blahut or Lin & Costello or online notes by Hall [google coding theory Hall] at Michigan State are also recommended.